# What is this filter switch doing to the AC line that triggers the switching power supply to function and power the rest of the unit?

Tags: power-supply

[image]
This board is identified as a filter power switch and is in is an Akai Sampler. It connects to a switching power supply which outputs the required volts to the rest of the unit.

Intuitively, I thought the switch was only toggling the AC line from open to closed. Now that I discovered the output connecter is always live, I know the switch is only filtering the the AC line. But what exactly does that mean for the switching power supply, causing the unit itself to "turn on"?

Considering the AC line is always live, is there a benefit to this method? Versus, just using the switch to completely cut the power.

[image]

Official Schematic for the part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What is this filter switch doing to the AC line that triggers the
> switching power supply to function and power the rest of the unit?*

It's probably switching the neutral line hence it is still disconnecting power to the device but (unfortunately) it's still leaving the live wire connected. I guess you measured the presence of live voltage with respect to the chassis or earth connection.

BTW, it's not a filter switch; it's a switch.

> *Considering the AC line is always live, is there a benefit to this
> method? Versus, just using the switch to completely cut the power.*

It's switching the neutral connection and this is not ideal but it will disconnect power to the circuit.

Comment: ahh okay. when looking for replacement parts, the supplier called it that. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You'd need to see the other side of that board to be sure, but one possibility is that there are poles to switch both live and neutral, but the live one has welded itself shut. If so ... replace!

Comment: @Andyaka when you say "unfortunately" would you say that this is a design flaw? Considering the sampler operates normally.

Comment: @allen it could be that the switch is broken as Brian said in his comment. Or, it could be that your incoming supply has live and neutral switched over inadvertently - you measure "live" on the brown wire or blue wire? It's not a showstopper of course because any pro going inside would always check that brown is live and if it turns out that neutral is live, a little extra thought might be needed. It isn't a safety issue to the user of the equipment. But it isn't ideal. If you see live on brown it's either a design fault or as per Brian's comment.

Comment: I hadn't considered miswired incoming supply but that's a good point. I have seen switches fail in this mode even from reputable manufacturers. Which Akai certainly has been since at least the 1970s, so I'd be surprised by a design flaw.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I did a continuity test on the switch itself and both sets of poles function normally. I added a schematic to make the circuit more clear.

Comment: My only guess is that AC is flowing through both capacitors even when the switch is open. Would that be normal then?

Comment: Then check C902/3 for both short and open. You wouldn't normally see full line voltage, but either C902 short (unlikely!) or C903 open would give you that.

Comment: @alien aha I see something now that you've added a tear-down of the circuit. The snubber capacitors across the switch contacts will transfer both live and neutral but at a high impedance. However, a high input impedance DVM will effectively measure line voltage still. Did you measure the high voltage with the orange circled connector unplugged?

Comment: @BrianDrummond will do! never thought to test them since the unit has been working normally. I really thought there was some sort of AC filtering magic going on.

Comment: @Andyaka OK! that makes a whole lotta sense then. I just found the schematic and wish I included it sooner. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Andyaka and yes I did!

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you for your input!

Comment: Sounds like that part of the circuit is working fine then @allen

Comment: @Andyaka I originally perceived the switching power supply was sensing if the AC line was filtered or not before it started to power the rest of the unit. But you definitely made me realize it was never that complicated. I learned a thing about my DVM.